# Show XML data in datagrid

Tags: c#, xml

I am doing a weather API project. The upcoming 7 days weather information is displaying successfully in message boxes.

Instead of message boxes, how can display all the data with a datagridview?

This is my current working code:

```
string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=keygoeshere&q={0}&days=7", city);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);
            foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("forecastday"))
            {
               MessageBox.Show((string)npc.Descendants("date").FirstOrDefault());
               MessageBox.Show("Max temp " + (string)npc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault());
               MessageBox.Show("Min temp " + (string)npc.Descendants("mintemp_c").FirstOrDefault());
               MessageBox.Show("Text " + (string)npc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault());
               MessageBox.Show("Icon " + (string)npc.Descendants("http"+"icon").FirstOrDefault());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put data into a DataTable and then make the DataTable the DataSource of the DGV.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Max Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Min Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Icon", typeof(Bitmap));

            string city = "London";


            string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=keygoeshere&q={0}&days=7", city);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);
            foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("forecastday"))
            {
                string iconUri = (string)npc.Descendants("icon").FirstOrDefault();
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                byte[] image = client.DownloadData("http:" + iconUri);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image);



                Bitmap newBitMap = new Bitmap(stream);
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (string)npc.Descendants("date").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)npc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)npc.Descendants("mintemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)npc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault(),
                    newBitMap
                });

            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice work thanks. but image is not displaying help me

Comment: Code now displays image.

Comment: @jdweng I took the liberty of editing the OP's key out of the code. If anyone else wants to use it, they can get their own key for free. Otherwise, the OP's apixu account might be closed down or charged or something if lots of people start using it.