# XML image how to display at data grid columns in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml

this the xml code 
this the image i have to display datagridview colums //cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png

```
<root>
<condition>
<text>Sunny</text>
<icon>//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png</icon>
<code>1000</code>
</condition>
</root>
```

this is the code I have tried in c#.net. all data will display correctly but image is not displaying the only path is displaying at the datagridview.how to display the image at datgridview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("country", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Max Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Min Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Icon", typeof(string));

            city = txttext.Text;

            string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?={0}&days=7", city);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);
            foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("forecastday"))
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                         (string)doc.Descendants("country").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc.Descendants("date").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc.Descendants("mintemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault(),
                           "http:" +(string)npc.Descendants( "icon").FirstOrDefault()
                       });

            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: See posting earlier today.  This is identical to another user that I help last week and today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833875/show-xml-data-in-datagrid/46834175#comment80616985_46834175.  You need to make the data column a BitMap and then download the image to a byte array before putting into DGV

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap  this displaying data grid columns

Comment: Not with the code posted.  The DataTable has 6 columns and you are adding 6 columns in the DataRow. The error would happen if the DataTable has 6 columns and you tried to add 7 columns to the DataRow.

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap this is out display at the data grid view

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap this is output display at the data grid view image is not displayed

Comment: Did you look at the code at the link.  It ran fine at work earlier today.  The code posted here is just putting a string into the column.  My code downloads the bytes and put into a BitMap and then adds BitMap to DGV column.  I think you may of missing the typeof(BitMap) when I added the column.

Comment: can you write the one sir.

Comment: See the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833875/show-xml-data-in-datagrid/46834175#comment80616985_46834175

Comment: same code i have written but ouput displayed at the datagrid view columns look like this System.Drawing.Bitmap

Comment: thanks a lot sir for help your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested code with your key, then removed.  This is the 3rd time I helping with this project.  Or is it the 4th?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string city = "London";
            string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=MyKey&q={0}&days=7", city);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);

            List<weather> we = new List<weather>();
            we.Add(new weather() { 
                Maxtemp = (string)doc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                Mintemp = (string)doc.Descendants("mintemp_c").FirstOrDefault()
            });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = we;

        }
    }

    public class weather
    {
        private string date;
        private string maxtemp;
        private string mintemp;
        private string maxwindmph;
        private string maxwindkph;
        private string humidity;

        public weather() { }
        public weather(string maxtemp, string mintemp, string maxwindmph, string maxwindkph, string humidity)
        {

            this.maxtemp = maxtemp;
            this.mintemp = mintemp;
            this.maxwindmph = maxwindmph;
            this.maxwindkph = maxwindkph;
            this.humidity = humidity;


        }


        public string Maxtemp
        {
            get { return maxtemp; }
            set { maxtemp = value; }
        }
        public string Mintemp
        {
            get { return mintemp; }
            set { mintemp = value; }
        }
        public string Maxwindmph
        {
            get { return maxwindmph; }
            set { maxwindmph = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are best sir